# C 2 dimension array

Tags: c

My code & result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int array[3][4]={{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}}, i;

    printf("array address:\n");

    for(i=0;i<=2;i++){
        printf("array[%d]=%p, address of array[%d]=%p, deference *array[%d]=%d\n",
            i, array[i], i, &array[i], i, *array[i]);
        printf("*(array+%d)=%2p, value of array+i=%p \n\n", 
            i, *(array+i), array+i);
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Result

```
array address:

array[0]=000000af1bfffc70, address of array[0]=000000af1bfffc70, dereference *array[0]=1
*(array+0)=af1bfffc70, value of array+i=000000af1bfffc70 

array[1]=000000af1bfffc80, address of array[1]=000000af1bfffc80, dereference *array[1]=5
*(array+1)=af1bfffc80, value of array+i=000000af1bfffc80 

array[2]=000000af1bfffc90, address of array[2]=000000af1bfffc90, dereference *array[2]=9
*(array+2)=af1bfffc90, value of array+i=000000af1bfffc90
```

My questions are:

1. Why array[i] and &array[i] got the same output 000000af1bfffc70 and *array[i]=1/5/9？ As my Knowledge, array[i] stored address for i-row array(address of 1/5/9?), and &array[i] seem the memory address for array[i], the same output, is said begin address 000000af1bfffc70 stored 000000af1bfffc70? but 000000af1bfffc70 is the address of value 1/5/9?
2. Also *(array+i), array+i the same? af1bfffc70 vs.000000af1bfffc70

Comment: Note: since `array[i]` and `&array[i]` as ... arguments are pointers to the same memory location, but are of different types, they _could_ print differently.  Those addresses, printed the same or not, would _equate_ the same.

Comment: `array[i]` and `&array[i]` would be different if you had an array of pointers. But for a 2-dimensional array they're the same.

Answer (score 0):

see https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf 6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators

1. > (for &) If the operand is the result of a unary * operator, neither that operator nor the & operator is evaluated and the result is as if both were omitted, except that the constraints on the operators still apply and the result is not an lvalue.

When `&` act on a pointer like `array[1]` which pointer to the address of value 5, it doesn't change. So `&array[i]` is same as `array[i]`

2. > (for *) If the operand has type "pointer to type", the result has type "type".

That's why `*(array+i)` is same as `array+i`.